# Alert with textbox sencha

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

It possible to get an alert with a textbox in sencha touch.Here i use the normal alert with text box.Instead i want to show the text box in

```
Ext.Msg.alert()
```

Can any please refer some refrence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked on sencha long time back.. Try this [thread.](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?157382-How-to-develop-Custom-Dialog%28popup%29-BOX-using-sencha-touch)